# Are Custom Options/Product Options Attributes? Fastest way to load, and parse through Options?

Tags: attributes, custom-options, product-collection

My question is in two parts.

1. When you call `$product->getOptions()`, does this mean Options is an attribute? For example, when you are trying to get the name or a custom attribute "custom_attribute" of a product, you will use:

   ```
   $product->getName();
   $product->getCustomAttribute()
   ```

   Is this the same for options?? Are product options held in the options attribute? Is there even an options attribute??
2. What is the fastest way to get the options only? I need to parse through the options to see if an options exists and then print it out. This takes way to much time to load since I have to do this in a product list view. For example, when you only need a products name and image you can use collections to grab only the attributes you need using:

   ```
   $collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');
   $collection->addAttributeToSelect('small_image');
   ```

   Can you do this with options?? As of right now I have to get the product id and then load the product to get the product options. This takes waaaayyyy too much time @_@. Urks my soul.

Answer (score 2):

So to answer you first question. Technically the options are set against the product like another attribute but then are not standard Magento product attributes. They are set on the function `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::_afterLoad`. What this function does is load each product option from a collection and then attach it to the current model.

```
protected function _afterLoad()
{
    parent::_afterLoad();
    /**
     * Load product options
     */
    if ($this->getHasOptions()) {
        foreach ($this->getProductOptionsCollection() as $option) {
            $option->setProduct($this);
            $this->addOption($option);
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

So you can simply access them like a normal attribute even though they are "special" in that case.

For you second question what you can do is to simply use the options model `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_option')` and then then get the product option collection by filtering by product.

You can do this via a call to `getProductOptionCollection` this takes in a product object as a parameter which I think you already have and then builds a collection of all the options.

There may be a better option to add options to the product list collection but I am not sure about that.